# How to get the request url while using moshi 'deferred' with retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I want to know how to get the request url when using retrofit 2.0 with moshi and 'Deferred' coroutine

Comment: ```call.request().url().toString()``` Do you want this one?

Comment: thanks, @Aziz Ahmed  I have just figured that out

Comment: If my answer is right please let me know. Every question  needs answer in stackoverflow so other user can get help.

Comment: Sure, it is right. You can paste it as answer to the question and i would mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is method to get the url from Request call.

`call.request().url().toString()`